# Does name of Executable matter for User Account Control Dialog?

Tags: windows, vb6, installation, uac

1) If I open a new vb6 standard exe project and don't add any code but just

2) compile right away to the desktop and give it a name containing the word 'Update' it has a UAC shield overlaying it.

And then if I run it I get the UAC dialog.

I have no antivirus except microsoft essentials on my windows vista home basic computer.

If it doesn't have Update (even just leaving out the letter 'e') in the name there's no UAC and no shield on the program's dialog.

I imagine that this is just an oddity on my computer or is there a list of words that trigger UAC?

Comment: I'd ask this on http://superuser.com or (?) http://serverfault.com as it's general Windows question.

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov IMO it is of concern more to people who program for windows rather than those who just use windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with VB6. It's a Windows feature called **Installer Detection Technology** introduced with Windows Vista. You can read it up on [this TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx). Basically, installer detection applies to

1. 32-bit applications
2. Applications without a requestedExecutionLevel
3. Interactive processes running as a Standard User with LUA enabled

Also mentioned is a check for certain keywords in the filename like "install," "setup," "update," etc. You can easily check this by renaming your compiled executable and/or [adding a manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755426/how-do-i-create-a-manifest-file-in-visual-basic-6-0).

Comment: Thanks, this explains it