# SStab not appearing correctly in different OS's

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-10, controls

I'm working on a legacy VB6 application in Windows 10. I'm currently trying to get the application to run seamlessly in Windows 10 and I'm coming across some issues. One of them is the SSTab control. See Image below:

[image]

Style, Tab Orientation, All the properties are identical, but as can be seen the text in Windows 7 looks proper vs Win 10. It seems to float left and when selected, one of the S's seems to get cut off the top and added in the 2nd line.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Right click program - Properties - Compatibility and choose Disable DPI Scaling.

Comment: Or better, do the work of dealing with High DPI properly if you don't want text blurring and bitmap pixilation.

Comment: @Noodles - Unfortunately that doesn't seem to fix the problem :(. I'm really not sure why the text appears floating left when no properties have been changed

Comment: Try choosing Win 7 in the version part of compatibility. There is the App Compat Kit from MS that allows you to set thousands of compat settings rather than just a few common ones in that compatability dialog.

Comment: @Noodles - I'll check it out. Thank you.

Comment: @noodle if you want to go ahead and answer the question with your last comment I'll accept it, since I don't want to leave this questin open for god knows how long. Thanks

Comment: STILL HAVING ISSUES WITH THIS. ANYONE CAN HELP????

Comment: Have you tried to create a manifest file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755426/how-do-i-create-a-manifest-file-in-visual-basic-6-0 and played with various configs (theming, dpi, ...)?

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not sure about the manifest as none of the other apps have it, i did mess around with DPI but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: You have to make the control wider and I also noticed that if you change the style of the control it aligns differently.

Comment: @vbdevelop I cannot unfortunately make it wider. there are multiple tabs and have the stay the same size. I was just wondering if there's any way to fix the text because in Win 7 the text appears correctlly and tab size is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing Win 7 in the version part of compatibility. There is the App **Compat Kit** from MS that allows you to set thousands of `compat` settings rather than just a few common ones in that compatibility dialog https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7352